# Get the first value from comma separated string in jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, html-lists

I am trying to create a filter option like this :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjyBn.png)

I am able to get the values from the comma separated string but not as expected as show below :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW64S.png)

On each click of checkbox on the left side I am getting the value of that checkbox and show it on the top right side.
In case I select Option1, It shows Option1, then If I select Option2, then it shows Option1,Option1,Option2. I wish remove that Option1 at the beginning.

Below is my code:

```js
 
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function()
  { 

   if(!$(this).is(':checked'))
      $('.badge li').remove();

   var favorite = [];
            
            $.each($("input[name='category']:checked"), function(){            
                favorite.push($(this).val());
            });
            
            var selecte = favorite.join(",")[0];


            $(".badge").append($("<li>").css({float:'left'}).html(selecte));

   var itemName = $('select option:selected').text(); 

         $('.uncheckall').show();

   $('.smallapply').show();

   var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');

   var empty = [].filter.call( textinputs, function( el )
   {
      return !el.checked
   });

   if (textinputs.length == empty.length)
   {       
       $('.uncheckall').hide();

    $('.smallapply').hide();
   }

  });
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled scrollbar" id="style-3">

   <li>
    <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="checkbox1" value="option1" class="custom-control-input">
    <small class="custom-control-indicator"></small>
    <small class="custom-control-description">Option1</small>
    </label>
  </li>

  <li>
   <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="checkbox2" value="option2" class="custom-control-input">
   <small class="custom-control-indicator"></small>
   <small class="custom-control-description">Option2</small>
  </label>
    </li>

    <li>
  <label class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="category" id="checkbox3" value="option3" class="custom-control-input">
  <small class="custom-control-indicator"></small>
  <small class="custom-control-description">Option3</small>
  </label>
    </li>
     </ul>
```

Comment: have a look at [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-store-list-checkbox-values-div/)

Comment: No still the same issue, I wish to separate them :  https://ibb.co/cKFBS6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

```js
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function()
{
    var value;

    if (this.checked) {
        value = $(this).val();
        $('.inline').append($('<li>', { text: value }));
        $('#select_all').show();
        $('.clearall').show();
    } else {
        $('.inline li').last().remove();
    }

    $(".inline").delegate("li", "click", function(){
        var checkboxElement=("input[name='category'][value='"+$(this).text()+"']");
        $(''+checkboxElement+'').prop('checked', false);
        $(this).remove();
        $(".inline").removeAttr('checked');
    });

    $(".inline").delegate("li", "click", function(){
        var allchecked = $('input[id^=checkbox]:checked').length;
        if (!allchecked)
        {
            $('.clearall').hide();
        };
    });

    var allchecked = $('input[id^=checkbox]:checked').length;
    if (!allchecked)
    {
        $('.clearall').hide();
    };

    $(".clearall").click(function(){

        $(".custom-control-input").prop('checked', false);
        $('.inline li').remove();
        $('.clearall').hide();
    });

    var itemName = $('select option:selected').text();

    $('.uncheckall').show();

    $('.smallapply').show();

    var textinputs = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
    var empty = [].filter.call( textinputs, function( el )
    {
        return !el.checked
    });

    if (textinputs.length == empty.length)
    {
        $('.uncheckall').hide();

        $('.smallapply').hide();
    }

});
```